# How do I use '더라도'?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean

클라라는 가더라도 저는 안 올 거예요.

Please tell me if my use of '더라도' is right. If it's not, then please explain to me how to use it. Thank you.

Comment: related: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/61/is-there-any-difference-in-meaning-between-the-더라도-and-도-verb-endings

Answer (score 1):

It's a grammar point connected to the verb stem, and basically means 'even if ....'. In your sentence, you're saying: Even if Clara goes, I am not coming.

Check this link for a more in dept explanation with examples: https://www.howtostudykorean.com/upper-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-4-lessons-92-100/lesson-99/